# Very strange edit to review

Tags: bug

Was given https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8576073 while doing some edit reviews. There is very little showing to suggest that this is a real edit. The text shown (ie "32-bit unsigned integer type.") is 29 characters long, matching the review comment. The edit proposer has a reputation of 14.9K so I would not expect to be reviewing their edits. I have just previously had an audit question and was not expecting another so soon.

So this looks like a very strange edit to be reviewing. Refreshing the page gave the same display. Might this be due to a bug somewhere?

[image]

Comment: That's a [tag wiki edit](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), which you need [trusted user](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) status (20k rep) to do without approval.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The edit is for a tag wiki, which requires 20k reputation to edit without going through review.  There's no bug here.

The edit is not providing a useful tag description, it should be rejected with the reason:

> Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag should be used. See the help center for more guidance.

Comment: OK thanks, but there is nothing on the page to say it is a tag wiki edit. The "markdown" area just above the "0 votes" appears empty and clicking on its pieces does not change the display. This is my very first review of tag wiki edit, so thanks again for the answer.

Comment: @AdrianHHH There is absolutely something on the page to say it's a tag wiki edit.  In the place where the post being edited would normally be shown it lists a tag, with the phrase "tag wiki excerpt".